# Assets 2.0 PHP Error

Tags: add-on, assets

Anyone getting this with the new Assets 2.0?  Receive the error when saving the channel field:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`exp_assets_folders`) WHERE `source_type` = 'ee' AND `source_id` = '1' AND `0` = 'parent_id'

Filename: third_party/assets/ft.assets.php

Line Number: 332
```

Running EE 2.5.5 and the Asset field is inside of a Matrix.

Comment: You, sir, receive the award for fastest-ever bug report. :)

Comment: Poor Brandon will never get to have that nap.

Comment: What version of Matrix are you running?  Was this an upgrade from 1.X (and if so, what version) or a fresh install?

Comment: Also, did you visit the Assets page after uploading the files?

Comment: Just wanted to check in and see if you still needed help with this? Please make sure you're on Assets 2.0.3.  thank you!